Textfield Focus inside dialog is rebuilding page
I have the following page but there is an issue, anytime I open any dialog and focus on a textfield, the dialog remains open, but the page behind it rebuilds, making it scroll to the top, even before I close the dialog. Just focusing on a textfield causes this.
Also I've tested on web and this does not happen, but when debugging on mobile it does.
Anyone understand why? Thank you
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.22.2, on Microsoft Windows
• Flutter version 3.22.2 on channel stable
• Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
• Framework revision 761747bfc5 (3 months ago), 2024-06-05 22:15:13 +0200
• Engine revision edd8546116
• Dart version 3.4.3
• DevTools version 2.34.3

class WorkoutReferencePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  final int id;
  final int firstWeek;
  final int curMacrocycle;
  final int? curWeek;

  const WorkoutReferencePage(
      {super.key,
      required this.title,
      required this.id,
      required this.firstWeek,
      required this.curMacrocycle,
      this.curWeek});

  @override
  WorkoutReferencePageState createState() => WorkoutReferencePageState();
}

class WorkoutReferencePageState extends State<WorkoutReferencePage> {
  final Map<String, TextEditingController> _setsControllers = {};
  final Map<String, TextEditingController> _repsControllers = {};
  final Map<String, TextEditingController> _weightControllers = {};
  final Map<String, TextEditingController> _notesControllers = {};
  final Map<String, int> _exerciseSets = {};

  final Map<String, TextEditingController> _warmupSetsControllers = {};
  final Map<String, TextEditingController> _warmupRepsControllers = {};
  final Map<String, TextEditingController> _warmupWeightControllers = {};
  final Map<String, TextEditingController> _warmupNotesControllers = {};
  final Map<String, int> _warmupExerciseSets = {};

  final Map<String, List<int>> _lastWeekReps = {};
  final Map<String, List<double>> _lastWeekWeights = {};
  final Map<String, List<int>> _thisWeekReps = {};
  final Map<String, List<double>> _thisWeekWeights = {};

  final Map<String, List<int>> _lastWeekWarmupReps = {};
  final Map<String, List<double>> _lastWeekWarmupWeights = {};
  final Map<String, List<int>> _thisWeekWarmupReps = {};
  final Map<String, List<double>> _thisWeekWarmupWeights = {};

  final Map<String, String> userNotes = {};
  final Map<String, String> userWarmupNotes = {};

  int dayNr = -1;

  bool _isLoading = true;

  final TextEditingController _newWorkoutNameController =
      TextEditingController();
  late String workoutName = widget.title;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    checkAdmin(context);
    _refreshData();
  }

  Future<void> fetchInitialValues() async {
    _newWorkoutNameController.text = workoutName;
    if (widget.curWeek != null) {
      dayNr = await FireStoreHelper.instance.findDayContainingWorkout(
          widget.id, widget.curMacrocycle, widget.curWeek ?? 1);
    }
    final exercisesSnapshot = await FireStoreHelper.instance
        .streamWorkoutExercisesOnline(widget.id, widget.firstWeek, false)
        .first;
    final warmupsSnapshot = await FireStoreHelper.instance
        .streamWorkoutExercisesOnline(widget.id, widget.firstWeek, true)
        .first;

    for (var exerciseData in exercisesSnapshot) {
      final exerciseId = exerciseData['Id'];
      final exerciseSetsSnapshot = await FireStoreHelper.instance
          .fetchWorkoutExerciseSetsOnline(
              widget.id, exerciseId, widget.firstWeek, false);

      final exerciseName = exerciseData['Nome'];
      _setsControllers[exerciseName] = TextEditingController()
        ..text = exerciseSetsSnapshot.toString(); // Initialize Sets controller
      _repsControllers[exerciseName] = TextEditingController()
        ..text = exerciseData['Reps'].toString(); // Initialize Reps controller
      _weightControllers[exerciseName] = TextEditingController()
        ..text =
            exerciseData['Peso_rec'].toString(); // Initialize Weight controller
      _notesControllers[exerciseName] = TextEditingController()
        ..text = exerciseData['Notas'] ?? ''; // Initialize Notes controller

      _exerciseSets[exerciseName] = exerciseSetsSnapshot;
      if (dayNr != -1 && widget.curWeek != null) {
        // Fetch last week and current week reps and weights
        final lastWeekValues = await FireStoreHelper.instance
            .fetchExerciseSetValues(widget.id, exerciseId,
                (widget.curWeek ?? 1) - 1, widget.curMacrocycle, dayNr, false);

        final currentWeekValues = await FireStoreHelper.instance
            .fetchExerciseSetValues(widget.id, exerciseId, widget.curWeek ?? 1,
                widget.curMacrocycle, dayNr, false);

        final thisWeeksNotes = await FireStoreHelper.instance.fetchExerciseNote(
            widget.id,
            exerciseId,
            widget.curWeek ?? 1,
            widget.curMacrocycle,
            dayNr,
            false);

        _lastWeekReps[exerciseName] = lastWeekValues['Reps'] as List<int>;
        _lastWeekWeights[exerciseName] = lastWeekValues['Peso'] as List<double>;
        _thisWeekReps[exerciseName] = currentWeekValues['Reps'] as List<int>;
        _thisWeekWeights[exerciseName] =
            currentWeekValues['Peso'] as List<double>;
        if (thisWeeksNotes != null && thisWeeksNotes.isNotEmpty) {
          userNotes[exerciseName] = thisWeeksNotes;
        }
      }
    }

    for (var exerciseData in warmupsSnapshot) {
      final exerciseId = exerciseData['Id'];
      final exerciseSetsSnapshot = await FireStoreHelper.instance
          .fetchWorkoutExerciseSetsOnline(
              widget.id, exerciseId, widget.firstWeek, true);

      final exerciseName = exerciseData['Nome'];
      _warmupSetsControllers[exerciseName] = TextEditingController()
        ..text = exerciseSetsSnapshot.toString(); // Initialize Sets controller
      _warmupRepsControllers[exerciseName] = TextEditingController()
        ..text = exerciseData['Reps'].toString(); // Initialize Reps controller
      _warmupWeightControllers[exerciseName] = TextEditingController()
        ..text =
            exerciseData['Peso_rec'].toString(); // Initialize Weight controller
      _warmupNotesControllers[exerciseName] = TextEditingController()
        ..text = exerciseData['Notas'] ?? ''; // Initialize Notes controller

      _warmupExerciseSets[exerciseName] = exerciseSetsSnapshot;

      if (dayNr != -1 && widget.curWeek != null) {
        // Fetch last week and current week reps and weights
        final lastWeekValues = await FireStoreHelper.instance
            .fetchExerciseSetValues(widget.id, exerciseId,
                (widget.curWeek ?? 1) - 1, widget.curMacrocycle, dayNr, true);
        final currentWeekValues = await FireStoreHelper.instance
            .fetchExerciseSetValues(widget.id, exerciseId, widget.curWeek ?? 1,
                widget.curMacrocycle, dayNr, true);

        final thisWeeksNotes = await FireStoreHelper.instance.fetchExerciseNote(
            widget.id,
            exerciseId,
            (widget.curWeek ?? 1) - 1,
            widget.curMacrocycle,
            dayNr,
            false);

        _lastWeekWarmupReps[exerciseName] = lastWeekValues['Reps'] as List<int>;
        _lastWeekWarmupWeights[exerciseName] =
            lastWeekValues['Peso'] as List<double>;
        _thisWeekWarmupReps[exerciseName] =
            currentWeekValues['Reps'] as List<int>;
        _thisWeekWarmupWeights[exerciseName] =
            currentWeekValues['Peso'] as List<double>;

        if (thisWeeksNotes != null && thisWeeksNotes.isNotEmpty) {
          userWarmupNotes[exerciseName] = thisWeeksNotes;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  Future<void> _refreshData() async {
    if (mounted) {
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = true;
      });
    }
    // Fetch and update the exercise data again
    await fetchInitialValues();

    // Add a check to ensure the widget is still mounted before calling setState
    if (mounted) {
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {
          _isLoading = false;
        });
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: const CustomAppBar(),
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Padding(
          padding:
              const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0, left: 15, right: 15, bottom: 0),
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    Flexible(
                      child: Text(
                        widget.title,
                        textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 22.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          // Makes it stand out as a title
                          color: Colors.black,
                          // Choose a color that fits your app's theme
                          letterSpacing: 0.5,
                          // Just a bit of spacing to add clarity
                          shadows: [
                            Shadow(
                              offset: const Offset(1.5, 1.5),
                              blurRadius: 3.0,
                              color: Colors.grey
                                  .withOpacity(0.5), // Soft shadow for depth
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        overflow: TextOverflow
                            .visible, // In case the title is too long
                      ),
                    ),
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        IconButton(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                          constraints: const BoxConstraints(),
                          alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                          onPressed: () {
                            changeWorkoutNameDialog(context);
                          },
                          icon: Icon(
                            Icons.edit,
                            shadows: [
                              Shadow(
                                offset: const Offset(-1.0, -1.0),
                                blurRadius: 3.0,
                                color: Colors.grey
                                    .withOpacity(0.5), // Soft shadow for depth
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        if (widget.firstWeek != 0)
                          IconButton(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                            constraints: const BoxConstraints(),
                            onPressed: () {
                              _transferWorkoutToFavoritesDialog(
                                widget.title,
                                widget.id,
                              );
                            },
                            icon: Icon(
                              Icons.star,
                              shadows: [
                                Shadow(
                                  offset: const Offset(-1.0, -1.0),
                                  blurRadius: 3.0,
                                  color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(
                                      0.5), // Soft shadow for depth
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                _isLoading // Show loading indicator while fetching data
                    ? const Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                        color: Color(0xFF002AD7),
                      ))
                    : Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: [
                          showWarmupDialog(context),
                          StreamBuilder<List<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
                              stream: FireStoreHelper.instance
                                  .streamWorkoutExercisesOnline(
                                      widget.id, widget.firstWeek, false),
                              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                                if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                                    ConnectionState.waiting) {
                                  return const CircularProgressIndicator(
                                    color: Color(0xFF002AD7),
                                  );
                                } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                                  return const Text(
                                      'Erro: Nenhum exercício encontrado.');
                                } else {
                                  final exercises = snapshot.data!;
                                  exercises.sort((a, b) {
                                    // Replace 'YourSortingKey' with the key you want to use for sorting the exercises.
                                    // For example, if you want to sort by exercise name, you can use 'Nome' as the key.
                                    final aValue = a['Ordem'];
                                    final bValue = b['Ordem'];
                                    // For ascending order, use 'compareTo'. For descending order, use '-1 * aValue.compareTo(bValue)'.
                                    return aValue.compareTo(bValue);
                                  });
                                  return buildExerciseCards(exercises, false);
                                }
                              }),
                          ElevatedButton(
                            onPressed: () async {
                              await Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) => ExerciseListPage(
                                    workoutName: widget.title,
                                    workoutId: widget.id,
                                    curWeek: widget.firstWeek,
                                    isWarmup: false,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ).then((_) => _refreshData());
                            },
                            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                              backgroundColor: const Color(0xff002ad7),
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                                    33), // Adjust the value as needed
                              ),
                            ),
                            child: const Text('Adicionar Exercício'),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(
                            height: 15.0,
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildExerciseCards(
      List<Map<String, dynamic>> exercises, bool isWarmup) {
    return ReorderableListView.builder(
      buildDefaultDragHandles: false,
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemCount: exercises.length,
      physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
      dragStartBehavior: DragStartBehavior.down,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        final exercise = exercises[index];
        final exerciseName = exercise['Nome'];
        final exerciseId = exercise['Id'];

        return ReorderableDelayedDragStartListener(
          index: index,
          key: Key(exerciseId.toString()),
          child: StatefulBuilder(
        builder: (context, newSetState) {
        return Card(
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
            ),
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
            key: Key(exerciseId.toString()),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                        child: Text(
                          exerciseName,
                          style: const TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                              fontSize: 18.0,
                              color: Colors.black),
                          textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                        ),
                      ),
                      buildEditExercise(isWarmup, exerciseName, exerciseId),
                      buildRemoveExercise(
                          context, exerciseId, exerciseName, isWarmup),
                    ],
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            'Séries: ${exercise['Sets'].toString()}',
                            style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                          Text(
                            'Reps: ${exercise['Reps'].toString()}',
                            style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                          Text(
                            'Peso recomendado: ${exercise['Peso_rec'].toString()}',
                            style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                        ],
                      ),
                      if (90.w >= 800 && widget.curWeek != null) ...[
                        Expanded(
                          child: _buildPreviousAndCurrentValues(
                              exerciseName, exerciseId, isWarmup, newSetState),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ],
                  ),
                  if (exercise['Notas'].toString().isNotEmpty) ...[
                    const Text("Notas:", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0)),
                    Container(
                      width: double.infinity,
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0, top: 2.0),
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                        border: Border.all(
                          color: Colors.grey.shade300,
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: Text(
                        exercise['Notas'].toString(),
                        style: const TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                          fontSize: 16.0,
                          color: Colors.black,
                        ),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                      ),
                    ),
                    if (90.w < 800 && widget.curWeek != null) ...[
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 10,
                      ),
                      _buildPreviousAndCurrentValues(
                          exerciseName, exerciseId, isWarmup, newSetState),
                    ],
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 10,
                    ),
                  ],
                ],
              ),
            ),
        );},
          ),
        );
      },
      onReorder: (oldIndex, newIndex) {
        if (mounted) {
          setState(() {
            if (newIndex > oldIndex) {
              newIndex -= 1;
            }
            final exercise = exercises.removeAt(oldIndex);
            exercises.insert(newIndex, exercise);

            // Update Firestore 'Ordem' values here based on the new order
            for (int i = 0; i < exercises.length; i++) {
              final exerciseId = exercises[i]['Id'];
              // Update 'Ordem' value in Firestore
              FireStoreHelper.instance.updateExerciseOrdem(
                widget.id,
                exerciseId,
                i + 1,
                widget.firstWeek,
                isWarmup,
                context,
              );
            }
          });
        }
      },
    );
  }

  IconButton buildEditExercise(bool isWarmup, exerciseName, exerciseId) {
    return IconButton(
      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
      color: const Color(0xff002ad7),
      constraints: const BoxConstraints(),
      onPressed: () {
        // Edit button action
        final setsController = isWarmup
            ? _warmupSetsControllers[exerciseName]!
            : _setsControllers[exerciseName]!;
        final repsController = isWarmup
            ? _warmupRepsControllers[exerciseName]!
            : _repsControllers[exerciseName]!;
        final weightController = isWarmup
            ? _warmupWeightControllers[exerciseName]!
            : _weightControllers[exerciseName]!;
        final notesController = isWarmup
            ? _warmupNotesControllers[exerciseName]!
            : _notesControllers[exerciseName]!;

        showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return StatefulBuilder(
              builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
                return AlertDialog(
                  title: Text('Editar $exerciseName'),
                  content: SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: ListBody(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
                          // Add spacing
                          child: TextFormField(
                            autofocus: true,
                            textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                            controller: setsController,
                            keyboardType: const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(
                                decimal: false),
                            decoration:
                                const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Séries'),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
                          // Add spacing
                          child: TextFormField(
                            controller: repsController,
                            textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                            decoration:
                                const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Reps'),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
                          // Add spacing
                          child: TextFormField(
                            controller: weightController,
                            textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                labelText: 'Peso recomendado'),
                          ),
                        ),
                        TextFormField(
                          controller: notesController,
                          onFieldSubmitted: (_) async => await saveEditExercise(
                              exerciseId,
                              exerciseName,
                              isWarmup,
                              setsController,
                              repsController,
                              weightController,
                              notesController,
                              context),
                          decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Notas'),
                          minLines: 1,
                          maxLines: null,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  actions: <Widget>[
                    CancelOutlinedButton(
                      context: context,
                    ),
                    OutlinedButton(
                        child: const Text('Guardar'),
                        onPressed: () async => await saveEditExercise(
                            exerciseId,
                            exerciseName,
                            isWarmup,
                            setsController,
                            repsController,
                            weightController,
                            notesController,
                            context)),
                  ],
                );
              },
            );
          },
        );
      },
      icon: const Icon(
        Icons.edit_outlined,
        size: 25,
      ),
    );
  }

  IconButton buildRemoveExercise(
      BuildContext context, exerciseId, exerciseName, bool isWarmup) {
    bool isRemovingExercise =
        false; // New state variable to track removal status

    return IconButton(
      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
      constraints: const BoxConstraints(),
      icon: const Icon(
        Icons.delete_outline,
        color: Colors.red,
        size: 25,
      ),
      onPressed: () async {
        showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
            title: Text(
              'Remover $exerciseName',
              style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
            content: const Text('Tem certeza que deseja remover o exercício?'),
            actions: [
              CancelOutlinedButton(context: context),
              OutlinedButton(
                onPressed: isRemovingExercise
                    ? null // Disable the button while removing exercise
                    : () async {
                        if (mounted) {
                          setState(() {
                            isRemovingExercise = true;
                          });
                        }
                        await FireStoreHelper.instance.removeExerciseOnline(
                            exerciseId,
                            widget.id,
                            widget.firstWeek,
                            isWarmup,
                            context);
                        if (mounted) {
                          setState(() {
                            isRemovingExercise = false;
                          });
                        }
                        if (context.mounted) {
                          Navigator.of(context).pop();
                        }
                      },
                child: const Text(
                  'Remover',
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }


I just need for the page not to rebuild on textfield focus. Even after using StatefulBuilder it did not solve.
